# Free/Open Source PPC Reporting Tool

Tags: gratis, open-source, reporting, analytics

I'm looking for a Free/Open Source PPC Reporting Tool. Here's what I'm looking for more specifically,

- The ability to connect to Google AdWords
- Export Report's to (or the ability to covert to) a PDF
- White Label, (Doesn't insert something like a watermark showing the tool used to create the report)
- Software (not a web app) that runs on Windows 10
- Free (not a trial) for commercial use

I would like to be able to include in the reports over a given time frame,

- Avg click through rate
- Total spend
- Total clicks
- Avg cost per click
- Total conversions
- Conversion rate
- Total impressions
- Average position

Some features I'm also looking for but aren't required are,

- Ability to connect to Bing Ads and create reports from that source
- Ability to show results in graphs and/or charts

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) which is a [python](http://python.org) toolkit:

- Free Gratis & Open Source
- Cross platform
- Allows you to query the various services that you need to provide the raw data
- lots of data manipulation and plotting tools
- likewise lots of export options, (with no default watermarks), *including to pdf via external libraries such as pandoc, reportlab, etc.*.
- you report can contain anything that Google AdWords or Bing Ads reports and any results from manipulation/combination of the data produces, e.g. you could, assuming the data from AdWords can be grouped by geographic location and date you could include a factor for the weather in the general geographic at the date for the location from another source.
- you can easily add new data sources

There is a good example of using pandas with Google Analytics [here](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/pandas-google-analytics.html) which ends with a nice graph that shows the views and visitors per hour for two domains using data fetched from Google Analytics.

[image: Example Plot]

Comment: Thank you, I'm more looking for an already made solution but I will take this under consideration